# how to extract strings of text from plain text files based on a keyword?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am a novice at computer programming, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have about 10,000 txt files and I want to extract strings of characters from those files based on key words. I want to then create a table with the name of the file of origin and string. I expect this table will have 10,000s of entries. The files I am using are plain text files, books to be specific, with zero markup of any kind.

For example, I would want to capture a string of 100 characters before and after the first instance of "Somalia" in the following text:

"In antiquity, the Horn of Africa was an important commercial centre. It is among the most probable locations of the fabled ancient Land of Punt. During the Middle Ages, several powerful Somali empires dominated the regional trade, including the Ajuran Empire, the Adal Sultanate, the Warsangali Sultanate, and the Geledi Sultanate. In the late 19th century, through a succession of treaties with these kingdoms, the British and Italians gained control of parts of the coast and established the colonies of British Somaliland and Italian Somaliland."

If I were to parse text and get a string of 100 charters before and after the first instance of Somalia, my string would look like this:

"ost probable locations of the fabled ancient Land of Punt. During the Middle Ages, several powerful Somali Somali empires dominated the regional trade, including the Ajuran Empire, the Adal Sultanate, the Wa"

Out of the 10,000 files, I expect to only find a hand full of files that have the key word Somalia, but I would search for thousands of keyword with 10,000s of results.

Where should I start in terms of looking for a script or program to do this task?

Comment: Maybe use http://regex101.com to test out what you want.  /(.{100}(?:Somalia).{100})/ would find a match for Somalia.

Comment: Where should I start in terms of looking for a script or program to do this task? `Google.!`

Comment: is it likely you will find "a program or a script" that happens to do exactly what you want and give the output you want? No, rather you should attempt to solve the problem yourself and if you get stuck you can post your code and the problem. Here you are simply asking others to write code for you. And questions asking "where can I find X" are not allowed on Stack

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses.     I already spent several days googling expressions like "extract sting plain text before after keyword." Everything I found was related to extraction from computer programming markup and I couldn't find anything that specifically dealt with my goal, so I tried this forum.

Comment: I added the suggested tags to my question and python was one of them, so you are correct Bob Dylan, I don't need to use python.

Comment: I'll definitely try out regex101.com. Thanks a lot for that suggestion.

Comment: user2266449, I am willing to do the work myself and ask for help when needed, but suggestions as to which programs to start with would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

path = "C://Users//Desktop//test"

for file_name in os.listdir(path):
     A=open(path+"//"+file_name).read()
     S = A.find("Somali")
     if(S==-1):
         print file_name+" Not found"

     else:
         print file_name+" "+A[A.find("Somali")-100:A.find("Somali")+100]
```

I will print list as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a ton Ravichandra! Is this in Javascript?

Comment: @daves I updated my code keep your files in `test` folder. By the way its Python

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Ravichandra +A[A.find("Somali")-100:A.find("Somali")+100] should be changed to +A[A.find("Somali")-100:A.find("Somali")+100+len("Somali")]

Comment: @LetzerWille Yes,Bro but as per his logic description you are correct and as per his example what I wrote is correct!!